# Mongodb get specific value by using corresponding id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
  "_id": 123,
  "username": "user123",
  "password": "pass123",
}
```

I want to search the database by id ("123") and get the corresponding username value ("user123") in Mongodb, but I really can't find a solution online.

Doing `.find( { _id: 123 }, { } );` returns ALL of the fields, where as I am only looking for whatever string the corresponding "username" field holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the fields that should be selected as below to the query

```
Model.find({_id: 123}, 'username -_id', (err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

`_id` will be always present in the result. Can exclude by adding `-_id`

Comment: Picking this is the answer since it solved my problem + helped me find a quick way to get rid of "_id" from the array

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating `_id` on your own? If not then do it like this:

```
.find({ _id: ObjectId("THE_ID") }, { username: 1 })
```

Usually, when you create a document, MongoDB automatically creates `_id` for you which is a hexadecimal string (type is `ObjectId`) and looks like this: ***"507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"***. The above query would work by this type of `_id`.

You can also assign your own `_id`. If your assigned id is not a type of `ObjectId` then a normal find query should work. But, remember, if `_id` is a string you have to search like a string, not as a number.

Comment: thank you, this was very insightful! I'm clearly new to mondoDB